# Spring Form post does not send ModelAttribute to controller

Tags: forms, spring, modelattribute

I'm still a beginner user with spring and web programming.

I'm trying to create a small form that would send a modelAttribute to another page but the modelAttribute is always null.

FileUploadForm.java

```
    public class FileUploadForm {

           CommonsMultipartFile file;   String blabla;

           // initiation of FileUploadForm.

           public FileUploadForm() {        
              // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub       
              file= null;   
           }        
           public String getBlabla() {      
             return blabla;
           }

           public void setBlabla( String blabla ) {         
               this.blabla = blabla;    
           }

          public CommonsMultipartFile getFile() {       
              return file;  
          }

          public void setFile(CommonsMultipartFile file) {      
             this.file = file;
          }

   }
```

MyuploadTest.jsp

```
<script>    
    function addFileToEcc() {
            document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target';
    };  

</script>
<div>
    <div id="titleSection" style="padding:5px;color:#303030;"class="ui-state-active, ui-widget-content ui-state-active, ui-widget-header ui-state-active"  onclick="$('#fourthSection').slideToggle();" >
        <label>detail</label>
    </div>

    <div id='AttachSection'>
        <form:form id="file_upload_form" action="NewfileUpload.do" method="post" modelAttribute="fileUploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" id='blabla' name="blabla" value="boubou" />
            <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src=""></iframe>                        
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

FileUploadController.java

```
@Controller     
    @SessionAttributes  
    public class FileUpload extends ServiceImpl {

        @Autowired
        Log log;        
        @Autowired 
        FileManagementService gFM;

    @RequestMapping( value = "/NewfileUpload.do", method = RequestMethod.POST ) 
    //      public ModelAndView uploadFile( @ModelAttribute FileUploadForm mainForm, HttpServletRequest pRequest ) {        
       public ModelAndView uploadFile( @ModelAttribute("fileUploadform") FileUploadForm mainForm, HttpServletRequest pRequest ) {
             log.info( "Begin File Upload." );
             FileUploadDetails fud = new FileUploadDetails();                            
             fud.setStatusCode( FileUploadDetails.STATUS_SUCCESS );

             return new ModelAndView( "fileUploaded", "fud", fud );                  
      } 
   }
```

I know that the code doesn't look pretty and would throw errors the way is is but I have setup a breakpoint in the FileUploadController.java file to check what are in the parameter passed to it and mainForm always returns null.

Anyone has an idea why it would be null while i know that my inputtext id="blabla" does have text in it.

THanks for you help

Comment: Please format your code. The method argument is wrongly named. You have an attribute called `fileUploadform` not `mainForm`. Either rename it in the JSP or in your controller. Also your controller looks suspicious why would a controller extend a `ServiceImpl`. Your form object shouldn't rely on `CommonsMultiPartFile` but on the common interface `MultiPartFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the Form-Object to the model when loading the page with your form via GET? Maybe something like this solves the problem:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/MyuploadTest", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String myUploadTest(Model model) {        
    model.addAttribute("fileUploadform", new FileUploadForm());
    return "MyuploadTest";                  
}
```

Comment: You are right Jeyp I did had that controller too which i forgot to add that part that was on my code as well.

 @RequestMapping( value = "/uploadTest.do", method = RequestMethod.GET )

 public String uploadScreen( Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("fileUploadform", new  FileUploadForm());
  System.out.println("uploadTest");
  return "MyuploadTest";
 }

Comment: sorry about the formatting not sure how to make it look formatted

Comment: Did you already change the other things that were mentioned by @M.Deinum above? If this does not help then also try this: Use `commandName="fileUploadform"` instead of `modelAttribute="fileUploadform"` which automatically sets the according id and name values.

Comment: This is what i don't understand


I know its going to the **FileUploadController** and my understanding that that spring should knows how to set the modelAttribute on post. but for reason the parameter *mainForm* in  *FileUploadController* has null data in it

Comment: It's because it is mapped to the name of the form id or name (I don't know atm). Anyways, you specify id as "file_upload_form" in your jsp and dont specifically specify a name, so nothing matches with `@ModelAttribute("fileUploadform")` in your Controller. You should go with `commandName="fileUploadform"` and leave id/name/modelAttribute values blank

Comment: M. Deinum, I changed the attribute to "fileUploadform".

I'm not sure about using the interface MultiPartFile instead of CommonsultiPartFile, the thing is that i base my code on a colleague project that working, the person has left the company tho so i can't  ask why he used CommonsMultiPartFile.

Comment: I removed the ids and put the commandName="fileUploadForm"    `<div id='AttachSection'>
   <form:form action="NewfileUpload.do" method="post" commandName="fileUploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button id='fileAdd' name="Submit Me" value="Upload" onClick="addFileToEcc();">this</button>
    <input type="text" value="boubou" />
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src=""></iframe>      
   </form:form>
  </div>` but still no luck. the attribute fileUploadform is still empty :(

Comment: Also try to use form:input as this adds binding to the command name. Using form:input, again, just specify path="blabla" and omit id/name. Is the form empty or is it null? Thats a difference.

Comment: Jeyp, when i debug with a checkpoint on  the parameter "fileUploadForm" in the the line "log.info("begin file upload") in the FileUploadController the parameter "FileUploadForm" has 2 properties "file" and "blablabla" both of them are null.

ok now i'm going somewhere, with the path i can debug and i load the page MyuploadTest.jsp it run through getBlabla() 
but when i submit it doesn't go and set the variable.

Comment: Can you update your question, so it matches the latest changes in your code? It's hard to put it all togheter, as there have been many small changes yet.

Comment: **MyUploadTest.jsp**   <div id='AttachSection'>
   <form:form action="NewfileUpload.do" commandName="fileUploadform"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <form:input path="blabla" value="boubou" />
     <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src=""></iframe>      
   </form:form>
  </div>

Comment: **FileUpload.java**   `@Controller
 @SessionAttributes
 public class FileUpload {

  @RequestMapping( value = "/NewfileUpload.do", method = RequestMethod.POST )
  public ModelAndView uploadFile( @ModelAttribute("fileUploadform") FileUploadForm pFile, HttpServletRequest pRequest ) {
   
   System.out.println( "Begin File Upload." );
   System.out.println(pFile.getBlabla());

       return new ModelAndView("FileUploadForm", "command", new FileUploadForm()); 
  }
 }`

Comment: **MyFileUploadTestController** `@Controller
@SessionAttributes( "FileUploadForm" )

public class MyuploadTestController {
// @ModelAttribute("FileUploadForm")
 
 
 @RequestMapping( value = "/uploadTest.do", method = RequestMethod.GET )

 public String uploadScreen( Model model, HttpServletRequest pRequest ) {
  model.addAttribute("fileUploadform", new  FileUploadForm());
  System.out.println("uploadTest");
  return "MyuploadTest";
 }
}`

Comment: yet i still have the same issue getBlabla() return null while it has boubou in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that you are not including the **form:input** Instead, you are using **input**, which will not work if you have the **form:form**
tag. You are also forgetting the path="modelAttributeName".